# Text CL/RF error in UniversalWindowsPlatform (Node.js + Xamarin)

Tags: node.js, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, cl

I am developing mobile with Xamarin and Node.js
and I want to post text using 'Editor'

In Xam.Android, Xam.iOS,
When I post text,
the result is

> aa
>
> bb

But In UWP

> aabb

When I checked text that post's body in client,
all platforms show correct body

But, When I check text that post's body in node

Android, iOS's body is correct, UWP's body is incorrect

How I solve this?

Comment: Question is, what is showing this body of text?

Comment: @Cheesebaron; If I post text in UWP, and text is showed 'aabb' in Android, iOS

Comment: You will need to normalize the line endings between the systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Android, iOS's body is correct, UWP's body is incorrect

The [`Editor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/editor) control is used to accept multi-line input. For my test, the line breaks for each platform are different.

IOS: `\n`

Android:`\n`

UWP:`\r`

So you could replace `\r` with `\n` in your client or make your node.js service support `\r` line break.

```
var Str = editor.Text.Replace("\r", "\n");
```